# how to check if plist is empty

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

How can i check whether is a plist is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your plist is an array:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:yourFile];
if ([array count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Your plist is empty");
}
```

Or if your plist is a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:yourFile];
if ([[dictionary allKeys] count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Your plist is empty");
}
```